# Not getting SQLQuery quite right - Double info

Tags: mysql, join

I use this QUERY

`SELECT id_mov, movimientos.id_expte, expte.id_expte, id_dr, detalle, fecha, plazo, expte 
FROM movimientos 
JOIN expte ON expte.id_expte=expte.id_expte
ORDER BY fecha DESC`

And get this response

```html
 <table class="table" id="table">
            
   <thead style="background-color:#337ab7">
              <tr>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Movimiento</th>
                <th>Expediente</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
   <tbody> 
  

 
              <tr>
                <td>2016-02-10</td>
                <td>Inicio demanda - Adj bono profesional, tasa y aporte.</td>
                <td>351516</td>
              </tr>
          

</tbody><tbody> 
  

 
              <tr>
                <td>2016-02-10</td>
                <td>Inicio demanda - Prox mov adjuntar bonos y demas cosas.</td>
                <td>351516</td>
              </tr>
          

</tbody><tbody> 

 
              <tr>
                <td>2016-02-10</td>
                <td>Inicio demanda - Adj bono profesional, tasa y aporte.</td>
                <td>134512</td>
              </tr>
          

</tbody><tbody> 

 
              <tr>
                <td>2016-02-10</td>
                <td>Inicio demanda - Prox mov adjuntar bonos y demas cosas.</td>
                <td>134512</td>
              </tr>
          

</tbody></table>
```

Now, my problem is that MOVIMIENTOS table has only 2 records but when i echo my query results with a WHILE it returns a list of 4 registries, when it should just be 2.

Any help is much apreciated. I'm new at this.

Comment: can't help you, since you haven't shown the code that actually process the DB response and builds the html.

Comment: are you trying to join two tables??
I don't think your join is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't join the table on the correct fields  .. try using

```
 SELECT id_mov, movimientos.id_expte, expte.id_expte, id_dr, detalle,
 fecha,    plazo, expte 
 FROM movimientos 
 JOIN expte ON  movimientos.id_expte=expte.id_expte
 ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Comment: God, how embarrasing.. you were right... thanks a lot.